# How do i check which radio button has been selected on python

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I was making a basic flashcard app and decided to give someone a true or false option for answering the question. I'm attempting to use the radio button widget from tkinter but I need help detecting which button has been selected. (the balancing list has the file names to pull from. the balanced and unbalanced for the radio buttons represents the true or false)

```
def random_balancing():

    #global balancing list creates list to pull from
    global balancing_list
    balancing_list = ['unbalanced1', 'unbalanced2', 'balanced1', 'balanced2']

    #globalizes the random number from element_list
    global rando
    rando = randint(0, 3)

    #globalizes the elements list
    global balancing1_list
    balancing_list1 = balancing_list[rando]

    #create element models
    global balancing1image
    balancing1_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('C:/Users/Kisitu/Desktop/project/balancing/' + balancing_list1 + '.png'))
    show_balancing1.config(image=balancing1_image)


def balancing():
    intro.pack_forget()
    hide_all_frames()
    balancing_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=1)

    global show_balancing1
    show_balancing1 = Label(balancing_frame)
    show_balancing1.pack(pady=15)

    #button to randomize state image
    rando_button3 = Button(balancing_frame, text="I Dont Know", command=balancing)
    rando_button3.pack(pady=10)

    global radio
    balanced = Radiobutton(balancing_frame,text="balanced", font=("Helvetica", 18))
    balanced.pack(pady=15)

    unbalanced = Radiobutton(balancing_frame,text="unbalanced", font=("Helvetica", 18))
    unbalanced.pack(pady=17)

    #answer button
    answer_button3 = Button(balancing_frame, text="answer", command=balancing_answer)
    answer_button3.pack(pady=5)

    #response label
    global answer_label3
    answer_label3 = Label(balancing_frame, text="", font=("Helvetica",18), bg='#B3FDFF')
    answer_label3.pack(pady=15)
    random_balancing()


def balancing_answer():
```

I don't know what I should put in the balancing_answer to detect which button is pressed. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please provide a minimal [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
 which means including all necessary imports and the code required to start your app.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
def sel(): #Command called whenever state of radiobutton is modified
    print(var.get)

var = StringVar() #Stringvariable to be slaved to both buttons
R1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Option 1", variable=var, value="Button1 selected", command=sel) #variable, value to set variable when selected and callback all defined.
R2 = Radiobutton(root, text="Option 2", variable=var, value="Button1 selected", command=sel)
```

A String variable is initiated and set to hold the value of the checked box.
Whenever the state of a button is modified sel() is called and the value printed out.

Let me know if any of this doesn't make sense.